# Elasticsearch-php 5.x - Can't put templates

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Using the official elasticsearch-php client, version 5.x.

I'm trying to put a template inside my Elasticsearch instance, but it simply 
doesn't return anything.

```
$data = [
        'name' => 'testTemplate',
        'body' => [
            'template' => 'testTemplate-*',
            'mappings' => [
                'foo' => 'string',
                'bar' => 'string',
            ],
        ],
    ];
$this->client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->allowBadJSONSerialization()
    ->setHosts($host)
    ->build();
$this->client->putTemplate($data);
```

I *must* use allowBadJsonSerialization() because i'm running on PHP 5.4, but on 5.6 it does the same thing.

I don't know if it's a bug or i'm doing something wrong.
Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using CURL according to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-templates.html).

Unfortunately the library doesn't work for the 5.x branch.